# How do i purge the contents of a text file in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Is there a command that can delete the contents of a file without opening it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563691/php-is-there-a-command-that-can-delete-the-contents-of-a-file-without-opening-i)

I have a bash script that runs a php file on a command line and sends the results to a text file.
for the "next" run of the bash script, i want to purge the previous results from the results file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jon's right. A simple `cp /dev/null yourfile` in your bash script would take care of it.

Comment: Although this way seems simple, it is not portable.

Answer (score 4):

[`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) will do that.

```
file_put_contents('text.txt', null);
```

Of course, you can also wipe out the contents of the file by redirecting output to it and writing anything from bash as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also truncate a file to a given size by doing:

```
ftruncate(fopen('text.txt'), 0);
```

That example will clear it, but 0 can be anything in the range [0 - size of file].

Comment: You need to `fclose()` it too. I think this approach isn't that convenient.