# erase all data from txt file - php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i purge the contents of a text file in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297570/how-do-i-purge-the-contents-of-a-text-file-in-php)

Hi..

How can I erase all the data stored (make blank) in my text file `myfile.txt` using php??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen ("/path/to/file.txt", "w+");
fclose($handle);
```

take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/fopen) for more info.

Answer (score 10):

PHP's [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) should be usefull in this case. Here's some example code:

```
file_put_contents('myfile.txt', '');
```

Comment: You've got your parameters backwards...

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
file_put_contents("myfile.txt", "");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = fopen('myfile.txt', 'w');
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "w+");
fwrite($handle , '');
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myFile = "myFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, "");
fclose($fh);
```