# Emptying a file with php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Is there a command that can delete the contents of a file without opening it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563691/php-is-there-a-command-that-can-delete-the-contents-of-a-file-without-opening-it)

How do you empty a .txt file on a server with a php command?

Comment: `unlink($file); $fp=fopen($file,'W');fclose($fp);`

Comment: don't you have any method off your head?

Comment: Or simply `file_put_contents($file, '');`

Comment: @ShaktiSingh `unlink` not remove but will make file unremovable. if it filling by zombie process it will continue grows up and you will lose the chance to save space. `echo '' > file` in `bash` is the best way that i know

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here's a way to only emptying if it already exists and that doesn't have the problem of using `file_exists`, as the the file may cease to exist between the `file_exists` call and the `fopen` call.

```
$f = @fopen("filename.txt", "r+");
if ($f !== false) {
    ftruncate($f, 0);
    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Looks like quite a robust approach :)

Comment: @Col. What about it? It is necessary to make fopen notice free.

Comment: @Col. fopen is one of the few places where `@` is necessary to have error-free code because it emits such notices in normal circumstances (e.g. fetching a remote file failed). If you followed PHP development, you'd know this topic was discussed and measures to be able to make PHP code `@` free (which is, we all agree, a desiratum) were proposed (e.g. like change it to be like `fsockopen`, giving back the error string). "if any error occurs" (this includes the file not existing or an open_basedir restriction), I would know because `$f` would return `false`, which is what I test for.

Comment: @Col. If you know an error occurs (return is `false`), you can still use `error_get_last` to get the error message.

Comment: @Col. Clearly 10 years of experience didn't teach you to discuss the issues on the merits. If you want to resort to authority/ad hominem, I could just tell you that I'm a PHP committer, who wrote the only changes to the stream subsystem in PHP 5.3.4 and leave it at that.

Comment: I had to deal with  tons of codes contains that stupid @mkdir's and @file's and such, made out of stupidest assumption that only ONE kind of error can be occurred, so, we hide that one error. and when error of other kind occurs, everything goes to up shit creek.

Comment: @Col. You realize that the script checks for error conditions, right? That's what the comparison with `false` is about. `@` doesn't ignore error conditions, it suppresses the error message. If you want to log the error message, you should obtain the error message with `error_get_last` and write it to the log (just like in Java you'd catch the exception and write it to the log instead of, say, relying on the exception reaching the unhandled exception handler and the stack trace being dumped to the log), hopefully with a more descriptive error message than "fopen failed in file x on line y".

Comment: @Col. So, the problem in PHP is not the `@` operator per se, it's emission of error messages in expected conditions that force the use of `@`. What is bad practice is using `@` to suppress error messages that could be suppressed by fixing the code or not checking the return of functions for an error value (usually `false`). What would be censurable would be writing `$f = fopen...` and go on without checking `$f` for `false`. You'd have an error message, but buggy code.

Comment: It is important that after "ftruncate", you use "rewind($f);". to return the pointer to the beginning of the file, otherwise it will be replaced by a NULL byte if you already have something in the file. (NULLNULLNULLnew-value)

Answer (score 31):

Write an empty string as the content of `filename.txt`:

```
file_put_contents('filename.txt', '');
```

Comment: As stated on php docs, this is the same as fopen, fwrite and fclose. Since fwrite is not required, this might be a bit slower than just fopen/fclose.

Answer (score 24):

```
$fh = fopen('filename.txt','w'); // Open and truncate the file
fclose($fh);
```

Or in one line and without storing the (temporary) file handle:

```
fclose(fopen('filename.txt','w'));
```

As others have stated, this creates the file in case it doesn't exist.

Comment: fclose(fopen('filename.txt','w'));

Answer (score 3):

Just open it for writing:

```
if (file_exists($path)) {     // Make sure we don't create the file
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');  // Sets the file size to zero bytes
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First delete it using `unlink()` and then just create a new empty file with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

With `ftruncate()`: http://php.net/ftruncate

Comment: For `ftruncate()` you have to `fopen()` it first.  If you `fopen()` for writing, the file is already truncated to zero bytes.

Comment: @Ferdinand depends on how you open it.

Comment: @Artefacto in general - yes. in this particular case - it's truncated already. Your comment has no sense and just annoying nitpicking.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer - The OP did not mention any of the special requirements other answers assume, such as "without opening it" or "without reading it". There are many ways to truncate a file, `ftruncate()` is a perfectly valid method and it's among the most generalizable ones. Whoever did it, I don't think the downvote is fair.

Comment: @Col. Hum? It's false that "in this particular case it's truncated already" as he didn't specify the arguments of `fopen`. In fact it *does* make sense to `fopen` with something other than `w` and use `ftruncate`, as I explain in my answer. Sorry if my comment offended you.

Comment: @Col. In case you haven't fully grasped my answer, it attempts to solve the problem of truncating a file that already exists, without ever creating a new file, which is something you cannot simply do with `fopen(file, 'w')`. But I appreciate your concern concerning the fashion in which I spend my time.

Comment: @Artefacto you can simply do it with fopen(file, 'w')

Comment: @Col. You can't. `fopen(file, 'w')` [will create the file if it doesn't exist](http://php.net/fopen).

Comment: @Artefacto nothing bad with it. You devised that problem off your head.

Comment: @Col. The answer asks how to empty a text file. Therefore, it assumes the file already exists. `fopen(file, 'w')` does empty a text file that already exists, but if the file does not exist, it creates. So it does **more** than what the question asks. Whether it's a problem or not, depends on the situation. In any case, I shall not continue this discussion, as you're clearly being -- pardon me -- an idiot; first making false statements and when confronted with the facts saying it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Artefacto it's you making false statements lol. And stupid answers too

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code

`

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

`
It will just override your file content to blank