# Simplify an array and save as CSV

Tags: php, arrays, clio-api

I have the really complex array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [matters] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1050370768
                    [client] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 939940280
                            [url] => /api/v2/contacts/939940280
                            [name] => Balter and Son
                        )

                    [display_number] => 00001-Balter and Son
                    [description] => Sueing for pain of having to program
                    [status] => Open
                    [open_date] => 2017-07-26
                    [close_date] =>
                    [pending_date] =>
                    [location] =>
                    [client_reference] => 34241
                    [responsible_attorney] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 345011996
                            [url] => /api/v2/users/345011996
                            [name] => jon balter
                            [email] => jbalter@seamlesssolutions.com
                        )

                    [originating_attorney] =>
                    [practice_area] =>
                    [billable] => 1
                    [maildrop_address] => ecd6d7b60+matter1050370768@maildrop.clio.com
                    [created_at] => 2017-07-26T20:46:14+00:00
                    [updated_at] => 2017-07-26T20:46:14+00:00
                    [custom_field_values] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [billing_method] => hourly
                    [group_id] => 1654280
                    [permission] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1654280
                            [url] => /api/v2/groups/1654280
                            [name] => Firm
                        )

                    [activity_rates] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1050770508
                    [client] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 940983330
                            [url] => /api/v2/contacts/940983330
                            [name] => Seamless Solutions
                        )

                    [display_number] => 00002-Seamless Solutions
                    [description] => This is a matter of life and death
                    [status] => Open
                    [open_date] => 2017-08-09
                    [close_date] =>
                    [pending_date] =>
                    [location] =>
                    [client_reference] =>
                    [responsible_attorney] =>
                    [originating_attorney] =>
                    [practice_area] =>
                    [billable] => 1
                    [maildrop_address] => ecd6d7b60+matter1050770508@maildrop.clio.com
                    [created_at] => 2017-08-09T21:37:28+00:00
                    [updated_at] => 2017-08-09T21:37:28+00:00
                    [custom_field_values] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [billing_method] => hourly
                    [group_id] => 1654280
                    [permission] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1654280
                            [url] => /api/v2/groups/1654280
                            [name] => Firm
                        )

                    [activity_rates] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [records] => 2
    [limit] => 200
    [next_offset] => 1050770508
    [order_dir] => asc
    [total_records] => 2
    [published_at] => 2017-08-09T21:37:38+00:00
)
```

I just want to get a return of 
Array (
 [display_number] => 00001-Balter and Son
[display_number] => 00002-Seamless Solutions
)

Then take this and save this as a CSV
00001,Balter and Son,
00002,Seamless Solutions

Any help would be awesome.
I know there has to be an easy way to do this.

Someone asked for the PHP.  Little hard to put here but I will try.  It is part of an API for CLIO legal software.

```
//Get Matters
$matterarry = matter_numbers ($token);

//get array to just matter numbers
$matternumbers = array(); // initialize the array to be used for the export
foreach($matterarry->matters as $key => $matter) { // loop through all the top level element
    // isolate the display number '00001' from '00001-Balter and Son'
    $displayNumber = explode('-', $matter->display_number);
    $displayNumber = $displayNumber[0];

    // push the element the export array using the display_number as the key
        $matternumbers[$key] = array(
            $displayNumber,  // '00001'
            $matter->client->name   // 'Balter and Son'
        );
    }
Print_r ($matternumbers);

//export to CSV
    $f = fopen('/tmp/matternumbers.csv', 'a');  // open the destination file handler
    fputcsv($f, array('display_number', 'name')); // start by adding the column headers
    // this can also be done by using named keys in your array, 
    // or having the first element be the value of the headers
    // I'm appending manually here for the sake of simplicity
    foreach($matternumbers as $key => $element) {
        fputcsv($f, $element); // append each element to the file
    }
    fclose($f); // don't forget to close the file ;)
function matter_numbers ( $token ) {
//$header = array('Authorization: bearer '.$token);
//print_r ($header);
$header = 'Authorization: bearer '.$token;
echo $header."\r\n";
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://app.goclio.com/api/v2/matters');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($header));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);

if( !$resp ) {
    die('Error: "' . curl_error( $ch ) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno( $ch ) );
}

else if ( 200 != curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE ) ) {
    echo "Bad Response Code!";
    echo "\n";
    echo "Response HTTP Status Code : " . curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
    echo "\n";
    echo "Response HTTP Body : " . $resp;
}
//print "curl response is:" . $resp;
$resp = json_decode($resp);

//print_r ($resp);
curl_close($ch);

    return $resp;
}
```

Comment: please show your actual php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try addressing the two parts of your question (1) simplifying the array to isolate specific elements and (2) exporting that to a `.csv` file

## Simplifying the array

For this you'll need to iterate over all the `matters` element of your original object and push whatever value(s) you wish to export in a new array with the appropriate format

```
$exportArray = array(); // initialize the array to be used for the export
foreach($initialObject->matters as $key => $matter) { // loop through all the top level element
    // isolate the display number '00001' from '00001-Balter and Son'
    $displayNumber = explode('-', $matter->display_number);
    $displayNumber = $displayNumber[0];

    // push the element the export array using the display_number as the key
    $exportArray[$key] = array(
        $displayNumber,  // '00001'
        $matter->client->name   // 'Balter and Son'
    );
}
```

You then end up with an array that should look a little something like that:

```
Array [
    0 => Array [
        0 => '00001'
        1 => 'Balter and Son'
    ]
    1 => Array [
        0 => '00002'
        1 => 'Seamless solutions'
    ]
]
```

Alternatively, instead of looping over the array you could use `array_map()` and obtain a similar result. If you're not familiar with `array_map()` you can find the official doc [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$exportArray = array_map(function($matter) {
    // isolate the display number '00001' from '00001-Balter and Son'
    $displayNumber = explode('-', $matter->display_number);
    $displayNumber = $displayNumber[0];

    return array(
        $displayNumber,
        $matter->client->name
    );
}, $initialObject->matters)
```

## Exporting to CSV

This part is actually quite easy as PHP has a function specifically for this ([Official Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php))

```
$f = fopen('/tmp/myFile.csv', 'a')  // open the destination file handler

fputcsv($f, array('display_number', 'name')) // start by adding the column headers
// this can also be done by using named keys in your array, 
// or having the first element be the value of the headers
// I'm appending manually here for the sake of simplicity
foreach($exportArray as $key => $element) {
    fputcsv($f, $element); // append each element to the file
}
fclose($f) // don't forget to close the file ;)
```

## Mixing the two together

Looping over the elements you want to export twice is tedious and will affect readability and maintainability. This is why you should probably mix those examples together in a single loop.

```
$file = fopen('/tmp/myFile.csv', 'a'); // open the destination file handler
fputcsv($file, array('display_number', 'name')); // add the column headers

foreach($initialObject->matters as $key => $matter) { // loop through all the top level element
    // isolate the display number '00001' from '00001-Balter and Son'
    $displayNumber = explode('-', $matter->display_number);
    $displayNumber = $displayNumber[0];

    // Add the information you need directly in the file
    fputcsv($file, array($displayNumber, $matter->client->name));
}
fclose($file);
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have assumed that your destination file is empty. If you don't know how to make sure a file is empty before starting working with, I suggest you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944388/emptying-a-file-with-php) question that sums it up very well.

Comment: DUDE. I mean DUDE.  You rock.

Comment: The 1st part works great.  Got me the array.  The export has an error.
Warning: fopen(/tmp/matternumbers.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Sites\Project

Comment: I fixed my error.  I am on a windows box so I had to give it a best path.