# how to auto empty content of text file if file size over large

Tags: php

i will create function to clear or empty the content if this file size over 5kb

Can anyone help me

How to check file size of text file , and empty all if file size over 5kb ,using php.

thank you

Comment: Try googling first, this is not hard to do (with even a little bit of research)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Is there a command that can delete the contents of a file without opening it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563691/php-is-there-a-command-that-can-delete-the-contents-of-a-file-without-opening-i)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've been googling but no idea. please help

Comment: how to auto empty that if filesize over 5kb

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for your requirement.

```
<?php
$filename   =   'my_file.txt';
$fileSize   =   filesize($filename);
$chkSizeInBytes =   "5000"; // (5KB in bytes)
$filePtr = fopen($filename, "r+");
if ($filePtr !== false) 
{
   if($fileSize >= $chkSizeInBytes)
   {
       ftruncate($filePtr, 0); // truncates the file with size 0
       fclose($filePtr); // Close resource
   }
}
?>
```